# Why isn't ionic updating package.json when installing a plugin or adding a platform?

Tags: ionic2

In my Ionic 2 app (latest beta [quickstart tutorial]) I installed a few additional plugins (e.g. cordova-plugin-geolocation) and platforms (e.g. android)

Plugins were installed via

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file --save #this added the plugin to config.xml but not package.json
```

Platforms instead:

```
ionic platform add android
```

cordovaPlugins and cordovaPlatforms are in package.json (as follows) but weren't modified by the 2 command above:

```
 "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
```

Now I'm not sure if this is really an issue (if so, I'll open a bug on the official repository) but apparently when running the project on another machine I need to run

```
ionic state restore
```

Answer (score 0):

(I found the answer just after posting)
Apparently  **ionic state save** does the trick